# $|f|^p$ is a function of bounded variation...

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let f be $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathscr{R}$. If $f$ is a fuction of bounded variation then $|f|^p$ is also a function of bounded variation, for any $1\leq p < \infty$

I'll try to write what I did. Suppose that f is a function of bounded variation. Then there is $M>0$ such that for every partition $P=\{x_{0},x_{1},...,x_{n}\}$. We have $\sum_{k=1}^{n}|{f(x_{k})-f(x_{k-1})|\leq M}$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^{n}||{f(x_{k})|^p-|f(x_{k-1})|^p|\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}|{(f(x_{k}))^p-(f(x_{k-1}))^p|}}$

That's all I've done.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MVT to show that $||x|^{p}-|y|^{p}| \leq p M^{p-1} |x-y|$ where $M =\max \{|a|,|b|\}$. From this your result follows by definition. [Replace $x$ by $f(x)$ and $y$ by $f(y)$ in this inequality].

Comment: But the Mean  Value Theorem is for continuous functions in [a,b] and derivable in (a,b). In this exercise, f is only a function of bounded variation.

Comment: I am not applying MVT to $f$. See the edited answer. I am only applying MVT to the function $x ^{p}$ on the real line.

Comment: It also helps to shift the interval $[a,b]$ to  to the right so that $a \geq 0$. Do you see why there is no loss of generality in assuming that $a \geq 0$?

Comment: No, I don't see it that clear...

Comment: If you define $g(t)=f(a+t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq b-a$ then the total variation of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is same as the total variation of $g$ on $[0,b-a]$.

Comment: In summary, your idea is to use MVT for the function $x^p$ with $1\leq p < \infty$ by taking $a>0$, right?

Comment: Yes. That is the best way to prove this result.

Comment: I have a question. How do you guarantee that the derivative of $x^p$ is bounded?

Comment: Since $f$ is of bounded variation it is bounded. Hence we only have to look at $x^{p}$ on a finite interval.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Aren't you applying MVT to $|x|^p?$

Comment: Yes, but we only have to consider this function on $[-M,M]$ where $M=\sup \{|f(x)|:a\leq x \leq b\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help